# Kotlin drawerLayout dirigirme a una actidad

Tags: android, kotlin, activity, android-intent, drawerlayout

Hola tengo el siguiente problema con un drawerLayout no puedo dirigirme a una actividad:

```
appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(
        setOf(
            R.id.nav_home,
            R.id.nav_deposit,
            R.id.nav_slideshow,
            R.id.nav_settings
        ), drawerLayout
    )

    setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
    navView.setupWithNavController(navController)
```

quiero dirigirme a una actividad cuando presione nav_settings

Answer (score 0):

Solucione de la siguiente manera =)

```
appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(
        setOf(
            R.id.nav_home,
            R.id.nav_deposit,
            R.id.nav_slideshow
        ), drawerLayout
    )

    setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
    navView.setupWithNavController(navController)

    navView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener {
        when(it.itemId) {
            R.id.nav_settings -> startActivity(Intent(this@MainActivity, SettingActivity::class.java))
            else -> NavigationUI.onNavDestinationSelected(it, navController)
        }
        drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
        true
    }
```

El orden si importa mucho.